# Count number of files in each subfolder, windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

There are many solutions for getting the total number of files within a directory using command line, but is there a way to get the number of files per sub directory using command line on Windows (powershell or CMD)?

Example:
We have the following structure:

```
root
  -> a
  -> b
  -> c
  -> d
```

The command requested would output something like:

```
a 5300
b 40
c 250
d 13
```

Comment: Sounds silly.. but can you also add if you want the command recurse subdirectories?  Do you want it to count subdirs as files too?

Answer (score 0):

> There are many solutions for getting the total number of files within a directory using command line, but is there a way to get the number of files per sub directory using command line on Windows (powershell or CMD)?

Use the exact same solution, only put it within a "for each directory" loop.

- In Cmd, use `for /d` to iterate over directories:

  ```
  for /d %a in (root\*) do example_command_to_count_files_in_dir "%~a"
  ```
- In PowerShell, use `ForEach-Object` (also known as `%`) to iterate over the results of `Get-ChildItem` (aka gci aka dir). Within the loop, `$_` is used to reference each item.

  ```
  gci root | % { something_to_count_files $_ }
  ```

For example, whether you use the Measure-Object method or the `@(dir)` method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14716609, you can just put the whole thing in the `%` script block:

```
dir root | % { $cout = (dir $_ -files | measure).count; echo "$_ has $count files"; }

dir root | % { $cout = @(dir $_).count; echo "$_ has $count items"; }
```

Of course, the same works with any other command that takes a directory name, whether it's a PowerShell built-in cmdlet or an external .exe.